# How to consider interaction terms in the ridge / lasso / elastic net?

Tags: regression, interaction, lasso, ridge-regression, elastic-net

I would like to ask a question about how to consider interaction terms in my penalized regression? My primary goal is to build the model to predict. I think in the conventional GLM, we run the model with only main effects firstly and then add the interactions with only significant main effects. But I am not sure how to operate in the penalized regression. Thanks.